# Synchronising threads between C++/CLI and C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, c++-cli

Say I have the following `C++/CLI` class:

```
public ref class ManagedDLAContainer {

private:
    DLAContainer* native_dla_container;
public:
    ManagedDLAContainer() : native_dla_container(new DLAContainer()) {}
    ~ManagedDLAContainer() { delete native_dla_container; }

    KeyValuePair<int,int> GetMRAParticle() {
        std::pair<int,int> mra_p = native_dla_container->mra_particle();
        KeyValuePair<int,int>^ mra_kvp = gcnew 
                     KeyValuePair<int,int>(mra_p.first, mra_p.second);
        return *mra_kvp;
    }

    size_t Size() {
        return native_dla_container->size();
    }

    void Generate(size_t _n) {
        native_dla_container->generate(_n);
    }

};
```

where `DLAContainer` is an unmanaged, native `C++` class. The method `generate` of this class does computationally intensive calculations involving building up a system of particles, whilst `mra_particle` returns a `std::pair<int,int>` representing the *most-recently-added* particle to the `DLAContainer`. This `C++/CLI` code is packaged in a class library which is then used by a `C#` WPF project.

The WPF project has the following class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
     private static readonly object locker = new object();
     private readonly ManagedDLAContainer dla;
     private KeyValuePair<int,int> mra_pair;
     private readonly AggregateSystemManager aggregate_manager;

     public MainWindow() {
         InitializeComponent();
         dla = new ManagedDLAContainer();
         mra_pair = new KeyValuePair<int,int>();
         aggregate_manager = new AggregateSystemManager();
         // a Model3DGroup which is part of the GUI
         WorldModels.Children.Add(aggregate_manager.AggregateSystemModel());
     }

     private void AggregateUpdateListener(uint _particle_slider_val){
         while (dla_2d.Size() < _particle_slider_val) {
             KeyValuePair<int,int> agg_kvp = dla.GetMRAParticle();
             if (agg_kvp.Equals(mra_pair) {
                 // no updates to aggregate
             }
             else {
                 mra_pair = agg_kvp;
                 Point3D position = new Point3D(agg_kvp.Key, agg_kvp.Value,0);
                 aggregate_manager.AddParticle(position);
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { aggregate_manager.Update(); } );
             }
         }
     }

     private void GenerateAggregate() {
         lock(locker) {
             uint particle_slider_val = 0;
             Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                 particle_slider_val = (uint)particles_slider.Value;
             });
             // start AggregateUpdateListener in new task
             Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AggregateUpdateListener(particle_slider_val));
             // generate the aggregate
             dla.Generate(particle_slider_val);
         }
     }

     private void GenerateButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
         // start GenerateAggregate method in new task
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateAggregate());
     }

}
```

### Explanation of Program Flow

- The user sets the number of particles to generate using the `particle_slider` GUI element, they then click the generate button.
- The method `GenerateAggregate` is run in a new task using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, this function then runs the `AggregateUpdateListener` in a separate task and finally calls `Generate` to produce the particle system.
- `AggregateUpdateListener` continuously runs whilst `Generate` is running and checks for updates to the *most-recently-added particle* and renders the new particles to the interface using the `AggregateManager` class as necessary.

### The Problem

Whilst this program is mostly successful, occasionally particles generated using `ManagedDLAContainer::Generate(size_t)` are missed by the `AggregateUpdateListener` method resulting in gaps in the particle system shown in the interface.

The issue here, I believe, is that the two processes (the generation of the particle system and the checking-rendering process) are not running in a correctly synchronised way. I need to somehow get it so that when a particle is added to the system an event is fired which allows `AggrgegateUpdateListener` to then perform the rendering and then hand the control back to generation.

I am unsure of how to do this however, as my `Generate` function will run non-stop in the background until the particle system has been generated completely up to the number of particles required - and this process is executed via the native `C++` code behind the scenes which has no knowledge whatsoever of my `C#` project. It is for this reason that I think using something like `AutoResetEvent` is not applicable in this case, *but if it is then please do let me know how!*

The only solution I can come up with at the moment (which has nothing to do with correctly synchronising the processes) is to iterate over the final particle system of the GUI and do comparison checks with the particle system container of the `C++` code (which will always be correct) and fill in any missing gaps in the former when a miss is detected from comparison with the latter. But this is a nasty "solution" and I'd much rather have it correctly running in real-time.

If any further information is required, let me know.

Comment: So, why do you not just use the Monitor class in the .NET part to synchronize?

Comment: Perhaps becaues the C++ part is not managed...?

Comment: There is no synchronization visible at all.  We'll have to take it on faith that "most-recently-added" means what it says.  You just have no guarantee that *most recently* is what you actually like.  The AggregateUpdateListener() method is going to be bogged down on the Invoke() call whenever the UI thread gets busy, or a garbage collection, that's completely random.  So could easily miss *two* added particles, it only sees the *most recently* added particle.  What seems to be missing is a thread-safe queue that can store the added particles.

Comment: Does DLAContainer even have a method that allows you to retrieve every particle processed?

Comment: @Slugart Not currently but that would be trivial to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a named Semaphore both in C++ and C# however it's probably a bit heavy as it's meant for synchronisation between processes.

Otherwise, following Hans' comment you could create a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) in the managed C++ part and expose it to the C# project.  You would then need to consume all the particles in the ManagedDLAContainer and enqueue them in the blocking queue.

In the C# GUI I'd recommend you have a timer every 200/250ms which when it fires dequeues all the available particles in the queue and then updates the GUI. Make sure to bound this by some max number of updates so that you don't get stuck constantly pulling items off the queue (if the native code is faster than the the C# code).

Comment: These are good suggestions, I'll take a look into `BlockingCollection` and see if I can get that to work.

Comment: I'll accept this answer now, I have implemented a `BlockingCollection` in the C++/CLI as well as a `std::queue` in my c++ code - seems to be working well, only problem now is that I get `deque iterator not dereferencable` when clearing and running the simulation again but that's something I should be able to figure out.